# jquery each function write less one record

Tags: jquery, each

I have following code

```
$.getJSON('/update-recent-stat', function(jsonData)
{
   var counterjson = 0;

   $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
        var i = counterjson++;
        var link = jsonData[i].linkid;
        var time = jsonData[i].time;
        var value = jsonData[i].tagvalue;
        var type = jsonData[i].type;
        var sender = jsonData[i].sender;

        $("#DownBoxL ul li:eq("+ i +")").html("<div class=Timestamp>"+time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+link+"\">"+sender+"</a> <?php echo $lang['sending'] ?> "+type+"!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value+"</div>");
     });
})
```

Also have a dependent file (updater) which queries the data and return the JSON file.
Now the problem is that this code writes one less record every time! Does anyone see the problem I have?

Comment: Why are you redefining `i`?

Comment: I guess `var i = counterjson++;` has something to do with it. It does not really seem to serve a purpose. What does it do? If you can't explain it, remove it.

Comment: why aren't you using the `value` parameter?  You're not using `each` in a way that provides any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Just remove this line:

```
var i = counterjson++;
```

You are reassigning `i` to a new variable. Try another variable:

```
$.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
        var j = counterjson++;
```

Comment: He is not really creating a new `i`, just overwriting the value with `counterjson++`.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(jsonData);`?

Answer (score 0):

You increment the `i` variable every time you execute that block of code. I think that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the parameters effectively and doing something like:

```
 $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
        var link = value.linkid;
        var time = value.time;
        var value = value.tagvalue; //<-- Shouldn't mask variables
        var type = value.type;
        var sender = value.sender;

        $("#DownBoxL ul li:eq("+ i +")").html("<div class=Timestamp>"+time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+link+"\">"+sender+"</a> <?php echo $lang['sending'] ?> "+type+"!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value+"</div>");
     });
```

Though you could also strip out the assignments and just have the one line.

```
$.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
        $("#DownBoxL ul li:eq("+ i +")").html("<div class=Timestamp>"+value.time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+value.link+"\">"+value.sender+"</a> <?php echo $lang['sending'] ?> "+value.type+"!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value.tagValue+"</div>");
     });
```

`each` populates the fist argument with the index so you shouldn't be tracking it manually, and the second argument with the appropriate object value so you don't need to retrieve that manually.  If you're not going to use it idomatically you should just use a `for` for clarity.

Comment: your suggestion is good but it does not solve the problem I have. thx.

Comment: It doesn't?  It should be functionally equivalent to what you have with far less code and less custom (i.e. more likely buggy) instructions

Comment: @onbids: Then please explain your problem better, provide some example input and output and preferably a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. The more information you provide, the easier it is for us to help you and you will get better answers.